# Basic XML R package question - how to return other attributes for matching entries?

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I've downloaded an XML database (Cellosaurus - https://web.expasy.org/cellosaurus/) and I'm trying to use the `XML` package in R to find all misspellings of a cell line name and return the misspelling and accession.

I've never used XML or XPath expressions before and I'm having real difficulties, so I also hope I've used the correct terminology in my question...

I've loaded the database like so:

```
doc <- XML::xmlInternalTreeParse(file)
```

and I can see an example entry which looks like this:

```
<cell-line category="Cancer cell line">
  <accession-list>
    <accession type="primary">CVCL_6774</accession>
  </accession-list>
  <name-list>
    <name type="identifier">DOV13</name>
  </name-list>
  <comment-list>
    <comment category="Misspelling"> DOR 13; In ArrayExpress E-MTAB-2706, PubMed=25485619 and PubMed=25877200 </comment>
  </comment-list>
```

I *think* I've managed to pull out all of the misspellings (which is slightly useful already):

```
mispelt <- XML::getNodeSet(doc, "//comment[@category=\"Misspelling\"]")
```

but now I have no idea how to get the *accession* associated with each misspelling. Perhaps there's a different function I should be using?

Can anyone help me out or point me towards a simple XML R package tutorial please?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help with an incomplete example. But the basic idea is to navigate up the tree structure to get to the data you want. I've used the more current `xml2` package but the same idea should hold for `XML`. For example

```
library(xml2)

xx <- read_xml("cell.xml")
nodes <- xml_find_all(xx, "//comment[@category=\"Misspelling\"]")
xml_find_first(nodes, ".//../../accession-list/accession") |> xml_text()
# [1] "CVCL_6774"
```

It's not clear if you have multiple comments or how your data is structured. You may need to `lapply` or `purrr::map` the second node selector after the first if you have multiple nodes

Comment: Thank you! Yes there are multiple comments so I will try as you suggest :) also, Bug's Life was a top film, thanks for reminding me of it :)